# Getting exception on running sh.status() command on MongoDB sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am running sh.status() command on my mongos instance of sharded Mongo cluster and I am getting below exception.

```
mongos> sh.status()
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=config.mongosTree: ping $gt new Date(1542173873192)\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions",
    "code" : 2
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:290:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
printShardingStatus@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:611:13
sh.status@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:78:5
@(shell):1:1

2018-11-14T05:38:55.904+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=config.mongosTree: ping $gt new Date(1542173873192)\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions",
    "code" : 2
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:290:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
printShardingStatus@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:611:13
sh.status@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:78:5
@(shell):1:1
```

I am running Mongo 3.2 on ubuntu 16.04 platform. It is working fine on MongoDB version 3.0 on ubuntu 14.04 platform. I have reinstalled everything and tried this on new machines too, everything is working fine except sh.status() command.

Thanks.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: Also Please also don't "spam tags". Tags on questions are for what the "question is about", and not the "full stack in use for your project". The fortunate thing is most of those tags simply don't exist on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was becuase [notablescan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.notablescan) property enabled in my mongo config servers. After disable `notablescan`, command is working fine. you can check status of `notablescan` by running this command.

```
db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, notablescan: 1 } )
```

Output would be like below if `notablescan` is enabled.

```
{
  "notablescan": true,
  "ok": 1
}
```